# PHP for Output Data and AJAX for Read it

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

The AJAX read only 2 nodes and when i try to read it, it give me undefined. Can you help me? I attach only client

https://i.stack.imgur.com/euygU.png (this is the "server")

```js
function funzione(regione)
        {    
           var site="http://www.example.it?regione="+regione; 
           var httpRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
           httpRequest.open("GET",site,false);
           httpRequest.send(null)       //per il metodo get e altri mettere qui i parametri al posto di null
           
           var testo=httpRequest.responseXML;
           alert(regione)
           if(httpRequest.status==200)
           {
            lista=testo.getElementsByTagName("provincia");
            for(i=0;i<lista.length;i++)
            {   
                nome=lista[i].firstChild.text;
                alert(nome);
            }
               }
           else
           {
            alert(httpRequest.status+" "+httpRequest.statusText);   
           }
        }
```

```html
<html> 
  <body>
        regione:<input type="text" name="regione" required><br>
        <input type="button" value="invia richiesta al server" onclick="funzione(regione.value)">
        <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I resolve it using -> nome=lista[i].lastChild.firstChild.text;

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the value of input by its name in this way.

You can select the input by tag, class, or id and then get its value.

Here's an example that uses `data-id` to get the id of the target input:

```js
function funzione(regione)
        {    
           var site="http://www.example.it?regione=lazio"; 
           var httpRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
           httpRequest.open("GET",site,false);
           httpRequest.send(null)       //per il metodo get e altri mettere qui i parametri al posto di null
           
           var testo=httpRequest.responseXML;
           alert(regione)
           if(httpRequest.status==200)
           {
            lista=testo.getElementsByTagName("provincia");
            for(i=0;i<lista.length;i++)
            {   
                nome=lista[i].firstChild.text;
                alert(nome);
            }
               }
           else
           {
            alert(httpRequest.status+" "+httpRequest.statusText);   
           }
        }
```

```html
<html> 
  <body>
        regione:<input type="text" name="regione" id="regione_input" required><br>
        <input type="button" data-id="regione_input" value="invia richiesta al server" onclick="funzione(this.getAttribute('data-id'))">
        <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are multiple ways to run the function on the input other than this.
You can also use `addEventListener` function instead of `onclick`;

Comment: the value pass without problem, the problem is in reading value from xml. I already test it

Comment: @Luca the error is on line 13 (`alert(regione)`) which says it cannot read regione value as it's not defined. `regione.value` isn't defined

Comment: It work, i receive value and i call site with no problem